# How do I erase an element of vector without application crashing due to lack of memory?

Tags: c++, memory, vector

So this problem is kind of hard to explain in a title so here it goes :

In my 32-bit application, I have a vector of point cloud that is for example, of size 4000. Let's say there is 20 000 points in each element of point cloud.

I wish to be able to delete a point cloud depending on whatever my condition is.

The problem is that, I am almost already hitting the Memory usage limit with my 4000 elements ( if for example I had 4500, my application would crash).

If I delete a point cloud when my vector size is 4000, it crashes, if it is a smaller size (lets say around 2000) it does not crash.

My theory : When erasing it, it re-allocates the vector somewhere else, but by doing so when I am near the memory limit, it hits the memory cap and crashes my app ?

Is there anyway to ensure the vector stays in that 'location' and not make my app crash or any other solution ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a deeper problem here. Deleting an object never should cause a crash. My guess is that you are continuing to refer to unallocated memory, but that is just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Are you iterate through vector ? Iterators are not valid after you delete some element from vector.

Comment: @Logicrat OTOH, erasing an element in the middle of a vector will require that following elements be copied across. Depending on the type stored in the vector, this may require some memory allocation. So there are scenarios where deleting something can result in memory being requested.

Comment: Is your vector a std::vector?

Comment: It is a std::vector of point clouds (which contain points). I don't think there is a way around my memory crash, so I'm gonna solve the problem differently, setting a bool to true or false for each point cloud on whether I want to keep it and once I go in my save function I'll ignore them.

Comment: std::vector does not reallocate for erase.  As @Logicrat said, the problem is deeper than a memory shortage.  If you are iterating, you might consider a *reverse* iterator.  That way, if you erase along the way, the iterator is still useful as you progress to the start of the vector.  Erasing as you use a *forward* iterator will invalidate it, though.

Comment: std::vector does not reallocate with erase, but there is something going on. My theory : It copies what is after the erase temporarily somewhere to then put it back after the element that was previous to the one erased. 
It clearly throws a bad alloc to my erase...
Is it possible to try this with a vector of ints/double that are almost to the memory cap of a 32 bit application?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about deleting vector element but I want to suggest you to change the elements order and not do reallocation.
I think that reorganize the vector will cost you less then reallocate new memory, and in the end of the vector you can mark the empty places with NULL or holding var that will represent the real size of the vector (in your case after deleting the point the real size will be 3999).
That way your allocation is done only once and you don't need to work with the OS allocator anymore.

Comment: This is a way to avoid the problem, but does not really address the cause of the crash.

Comment: I think that he\she mentioned that the crush cause by maximum memory usage, I don't think there is a way to get over it. even if I think it will be much more expansive then reorganize the vector.

Comment: Yeah, that would take forever unfortunately, and I'm not even sure that solves the memory issue... it might. I posted what I think I'll be doing as a comment to initial post, thanks for suggestions!